# Add multiple projects programmatically into Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, envdte

How to add multiple projects programmatically into a Visual Studio solution?

If I am using

```
solution.addfromtemplate(template1);
solution.addfromtemplate(template2);
```

Then it overwrites project with template1?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you are willing to achieve. If you are creating a VSX package, you are able to use the top-level object in the Visual Studio automation object model - DTE:

```
var dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
Solution2 sln= (Solution2)dte.Solution;
//this will create a solution
sln.Create("<PATH>", "<SOLUTION NAME>");

//here you get the project template which you want to use     
string csTemplatePath = sln.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp"); 
sln.AddFromTemplate(csTemplatePath, @"C:\fooFolder\FooBar", "Foo", false);
```

Comment: But if I do again sln.AddFromTemplate(...);Then it overwrites existing project instead of creating another project.

Comment: Did you change the third argument of the method which happens to be the Project Name? If not - that's why the existing one is overwritten. FMI see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767.aspx